# Create character sheet using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I currently modding for F1 Challenge 99 02 and i want to change the game font. The format F1C uses is basically a sheet of characters arranged in a grid-like formation. Below is an example:

[image: character sheet]

How can i make similar images with a desired font using Imagemagick (or other cli software)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified one of my Windows scripts and tested it with ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 on a bash shell.

The first part of it uses a couple "for" loops and "sed" to create a text file containing a list of all the characters.

```
> chars.txt

for x in 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F ;
   do for y in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F ;
      do echo X | sed "s/.*/label:\x${x}${y}/g" >> chars.txt ;
   done ;
done
```

The lines in that file look like this...

```
label: 
label:!
label:"
label:#
label:$
label:%
...
```

The prefix "label:" on each line lets IM read that file as if it's a long list of individual labels. IM reads that file like this "@chars.txt" to get all the images to create the character sheet. Here is the IM command that works on my bash...

```
imfont=Times-Roman

convert -font ${imfont} -pointsize 24 -size 36x36 -gravity center -background none \
   label:"\ " @chars.txt +gravity -compose copy -bordercolor blue -shave 1 -border 1 \
   +append +repage -crop 360x36 -append +repage charsheet.png
```

You should be able to make the grid from any installed font by setting the variable "imfont" to your choice.

The grid is created on a transparent background. To put it on a colored background, white for example, use "`-background #FFFFFF -flatten`" before writing the output file.

Edited to add: Notice how the command includes the "label:\ " for the space character ahead of reading the list of labels. On my installation IM won't make a label for a space unless I escape it with a backslash "\", so I just add that label manually.

Comment: Sadly the lack of the red pixel on the top (delimiting the width of each character) makes the sheet to render garbled on F1C...